# What's the difference between `/:foo*` and `/:foo(.*)` in express routes?

Tags: javascript, express

In express, we can define some endpoints with some paths:

```
app.get('/:foo*', function(req, res) { ... });

app.get('/:foo(.*)', function(req, res) { ... });
```

The two paths are quite similar, what's the difference between them?

Comment: A low level explanation would be to say they compile to very different regular expressions, the first to: `/^(?:\/([^\\/]+?(?:\/[^\\/]+?)*))?(?:\/(?=$))?$/i` and the second to `/^\/(.*)(?:\/(?=$))?$/i`

Comment: Looks like a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to me.

Answer (score 1):

`*` matches zero or more of the preceding tokens

Given the string `/:foo/apple/banana/:foo/:1234`

```
/:foo* matches: /:foo/apple/banana/:foo/:1234
                ^^^^^             ^^^^^
```

`(.*)` is a capturing group which will match all 0 or more of the preceding characters. The character in question is a wild card which means when we see `/:foo` we will continue to match until we reach the end of the string

Given the string `/hello/world/:foo/bar?id=123`

```
/:foo(.*) matches /hello/world/:foo/bar?id=123
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```